# Can't install mongodb for ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

**Trying to install mongodb for ubuntu and can't solve the issue.
I got lost, need your help please!**

Going according the docs:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

1. `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

Result (CLI output): on mine ubuntu:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

2. `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list`

Result (CLI output):

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
```

3. `sudo apt-get update`

Result (CLI output):

```
et:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Ign:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease                           
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                     
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release                             
Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease                           
Hit:7 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                           
Ign:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/upubuntu-com/xampp/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Hit:9 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease   
Hit:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release                            
Hit:12 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                
Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/upubuntu-com/xampp/ubuntu jammy Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/4.0/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/upubuntu-com/xampp/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/6.0/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

4. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

Result (CLI output):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

`uname -m`

Result (CLI output):

```
x86_64
```

`lsb_release -a`

Result (CLI output):

```
No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Release:    22.04

Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 9):

Good evening, I was having the same problem which was basically the lack of **libssl1.1**

What I did to solve it was to add the repository that contains this lib to download, in this case I used the ****focal repository****.

Use this command in your terminal to add it to your system:

**`echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list`**

Then do an update:

**`sudo apt-get update`**

And finally install the library:

**`sudo apt install libssl1.1`**

After installed try to install mongodb again, if it worked I'm glad to have helped you, if the problem persists I don't know how I can help you :(

Comment: .. it is working!! TX

Comment: I have the same error. Your approach didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

This is happening in `Ubuntu 20.04` recently as gpg keys not getting loaded properly.

Import the public key

```
curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \
   sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \
   --dearmor
```

Create list file where `mongodb-server-7.0.gpg` file location is added by `signed-by`

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
```

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I hope it works for you !

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzJ8xppcxM4

I'm trying from lajunta channel, with a little bit modification.

```
sudo apt-key export 64C3C388 | sudo gpg.d --dearmour -o /etc/apt/keyrings/mongod.gpg
```

you must find **keyrings** directory, my keyrings is in **apt**, maybe not the same with you and in the video.

then change directory to :

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

and next, follow installation documentation on the website.

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Hope this help...